# Split a list of lists

Tags: python

How can I split a list of lists per lines?

```
list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

into:

```
a b c  
d e f  
g h i
```

Comment: Unrelated, but it is generally best practice to not use `list` as a variable name since that is the name of a builtin function.

Comment: Wow, the continuous pop-up of "an edit has been made to this post; click to load" on *ALL* the answers makes it hard to choose to vote up...

Comment: To expand on @mgilson's comment, [python naming convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) is to use a synonym over a keyword with a trailing underscore over an abbreviation over a keyword.  For example, `sequence` > `list_` > `lst` > `list`.

Comment: @okm But it makes sure that when you comment on somebody's post they have not changed it in the meantime. That happened to me once...

Comment: @jamylak Has happened twice to me today XD

Comment: @jamylak Yes it's nice function. Just wanted to express the feeling that all players are rushing to update their answers =) I'm not very good at express it in English, any hint?

Comment: I understand what you mean, remember that you can remove the upvote or downvote after they make an edit so it is alright in that sense. I think it's a good feature.

Answer (score 7):

```
In [11]: lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

In [12]: print('\n'.join(' '.join(l) for l in lst))
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
PS: list name for that list was just an example.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [1]: mylist = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

In [2]: for item in mylist:
   ...:     print ' '.join(item)

a b c
d e f
g h i
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to split the elements, you want to [join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them:

```
>>> lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(sublist) for sublist in lst))
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

Note that `list` is a terrible name for a variable since it overshadows the built-in [`list`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list). Therefore, I renamed the variable to `lst`.

Comment: There is no need for your generator expression. ``(subel for subel in sublist)`` is the same as ``sublist``.

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
for subList in myList:
    print " ".join(subList)
```

(Note -- don't use reserved words like `list` or `str` to name your variables. This will bite you sooner rather than later)